# Setting an "advanced" css class value with javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, web

I have been trying to get this to work for a while now to no avail. Either I manage to break the whole page or it simply doesn't do anything.

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(window).innerHeight();
    $('a[id="st2"]:target~#scrollbg article.panel').css('-webkit-transform','translateY(-'height'px)');

});
```

trying to change the value of this css class:

```
a[id="st2"]:target~#scrollbg article.panel {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-955px);
    transform: translateY(-955px);
}
```

(the -955 value comes from me having manually entered the value so that it works in my browser/screen res.)

Now I'm well aware that I could just scrap the whole css-animation and do everything in javaScript instead but I still thought that I'd try asking for help first.

Cheers,

/chok

Comment: should `a[id="st2"]` not be: `a#st2` ?

Comment: @nico `#st2` is enough.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan that is correct of course.

Comment: Thanks for confirming this as well, I thought of changing it but let it be while fixing the "real" issue to reduce the amount of possible errors in the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
'translateY(-'height'px)');
```

should be

`'translateY(-'+height+'px)');`

Note the +. Otherwise, it ends up being a syntax error.

Comment: Yes that's exactly it! Thank's a lot mate.

Comment: @Chokladio - No worries.